как создать "указатель" на переменную в python
я довольно много писал на С и С++, но в python я разбираюсь очень плохо.
у меня есть такая проблема. мне нужно создать указатель на переменную
в С или С++ я могу сделать так
int a = 5;
int* b = &a;
a++;
std::cout << *b;

все изменения в "a" будут и в "b", но в python нет логики указателей. не хотелось бы делать костыли с массивом-памятью и переменными адресами. есть способ сделать это без костылей?

Они считают это преимуществом языка :) Как вам такой вариант? `import ctypes
a = ctypes.c_int(5)
b = ctypes.pointer(a)
a.value += 1
print(b.contents.value)`
Или работать со списком, например...

В Python нет указателей на переменные, есть ссылки на значения. Можно использовать простой объект контейнер, в котором будет храниться значение, и ссылаться на этот контейнер в двух переменных. Но в целом не нужно тянуть сишную логику в Python.
